# jquery post call function n times but wait for each to complete before calling next one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list things that I'm sending to PHP one at a time via `$.post`. I want to wait for each to complete before calling the next. I want to do this with JS not doing the looping with PHP as I want the return value from each to display.

```
var list = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  $.post(con, {
    callScript: list[i],
  }, function(data, status) {
    //Do stuff here with the data on success

  });
}
```

I have looked at `$.when` but just can't sort out how to use it. Ever example assumes that there is a set number of functions and not the same function n times. I also know that async false is not allowed.

Is there a way to get that to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is your good friend here. You can create a function that invokes itself for each item, calling the next one after the async operation of the current one is finished. The recursion stops when we run out of items.

```
function postInOrder(list, index = 0) {
  if (index < list.length) {
    $.post(con, {
      callScript: list[index],
    }, function success(data, status) {
      // do stuff here with the data on success
      // ...
      postInOrder(list, index + 1); // <-- run next script on completion
    });
  }
}

postInOrder(["a", "b", "c"])
```

Here's an example with a fake `post` method:

```js
function postInOrder(list, index = 0) {
  if (index < list.length) {
    console.log(`Start: ${list[index]}`)
    post(function success() {
      console.log(`Finish: ${list[index]}`)
      postInOrder(list, index + 1); // <-- run next script on completion
    });
  }
}

postInOrder(["a", "b", "c"])

function post(cb) { setTimeout(cb, 1000); }
```

Comment: Nice, hadn't thought of recursing them. Will give that a try.

Comment: This was way easier to understand than what @Jonas had and works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You may also reduce it to a promise queue:

```
list.reduce(function(prom,listEl){
  return prom.then(function(){
   return new Promise(function(next){
    $.post(con, {
      callScript: listEl,
    }, function(data, status) {
      //Do stuff here with the data on success
      next();
    });
  });
 });
},Promise.resolve());
```

(I think wrapping into a promise is not neccessary, may someone whos shure about jquerys syntax feels free to edit ;))

Comment: You should return the chain from within reduce.

Comment: I have no idea what that means @num035

Comment: @PaulNeale Jonas is building a chain of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that execute asynchronously one after the other, in order. This is a modern solution you should consider if your environment supports promises.

Answer (score 0):

There is a VERY widely used library called "async" that makes this sort of thing very easy.  Here are the docs for [async series](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) which is probably what you want to do here.

Here is the example from the docs:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback) {
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});
```

The pattern for the callback is pass an error as the first parameter if something went wrong, otherwise pass a null as the first parameter then the actual return value as the second parameter.  That pattern is used all over asynchronous JavaScript on the server and in the browser.

That final function is what gets executed once the series is complete.

You can also get tricky with this knowing that variables can be functions in JavaScript and build your queue like this:

```
var processMe = [];

processMe.push(callScript('two'));
processMe.push(callScript('four'));
processMe.push(callScript('six'));

async.series([ processMe ],
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equal to ['two', 'four', 'six']
});

function callScript(value, callback) {
  // do something here
  callback(null, value);
}
```

You can also use [waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) if you need to pass results from one step to another.

If it truly is the same code multiple times, use the [times](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#times) operator to simply iterate the same function N times:

```
// Pretend this is some complicated async factory
var createUser = function(id, callback) {
    callback(null, {
        id: 'user' + id
    });
};

// generate 5 users
async.times(5, function(n, next) {
    createUser(n, function(err, user) {
        next(err, user);
    });
}, function(err, users) {
    // we should now have 5 users
});
```

Comment: Will that work when calling the same function over and over? What I see in the example is a list of functions. I need n of the same function.

Comment: Sure, that would work.  Just create the array with a for loop.  There's also an async call called "times" that takes a parameter with the number of times you want to run it.  I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I took another look at your posted code, you do want series and not times.

Comment: Thanks. The recursion method still appears to be the easiest to setup.

Comment: Just beware of the dangers of recursive code.  I've been on several enterprise projects where it's banned, and we have standards against using it in my new development team.

Comment: Can I ask why it is banned? What are the dangers? I have been using recursive code for 20 years in every other language that I have ever dealt with and not had an issue. In fact the only way to do certain things is with recursion.

Comment: Potential run conditions and memory usage on large recursive trees.  Async coding and the easy availability of queue processing have changed how we (subjectively) view recursion - I learned recursion as a valid technique in college 25 years ago, but times have changed. I wouldn't allow a recursive function to be deployed into our production environment for those reasons alone.  I have seen inexperienced coders write poor recursion algorithms that have brought servers to a crawl, and not everyone we hire is an experienced developer who we can trust to write safe recursion.

Comment: I'll also add that it's not an issue in small programs, but when you recursively try to process hundreds of thousands or millions of steps that's when you can get into trouble.  Again, an experienced programmer should know not to use recursion in those instances but in today's marketplace just one time used improperly results in downtime and a big hit to a startup's reputation.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I too avoid large recursive solutions, I guess I know better.

Comment: @graham thats wrong. The upper code is not really recursive, its pseudo recursive and therefore quite memory wise.

Comment: Sure, but read my other comments for more context.  Decisions like this are not always about the efficiency of the code.